# How to show admob ads at bottom of tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

i know this question was asked earlier many times but all those answers not worked for me...

i have a activity with drawerlayout, tablayout and viewpager i want to show admob ads at bottom of viewpager so that it the ads keep showing at the bottom while user swipes through the viewpager .

here is my code :

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                layout="@layout/app_bar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/lightPrimaryColor"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/textIcons"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_contentframe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawerlist"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

i tried to add admob AD like this below viewpager and framelayout : but this does not show ad on screen

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/admob"
        layout="@layout/admob" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my answer .Inform me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) And set `android:layout_alignParentBottom` **true**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/admob"
        layout="@layout/admob" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**android:layout_alignParentBottom**

If true, makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of the parent. Accommodates bottom margin.

Comment: it does not make any difference  :(  still not seen adview

Comment: @Jaydeep did you use android:layout_below ??

Comment: yes i also tried it   : layout below   id/viewpager

Comment: @Jaydeep Try once again .Use RL instead LinearL

Comment: thanks it works now.. i have posted my code below , please check i have implemented it correctly....

Answer (score 2):

following @IntelliJ Amiya 's suggestions i have got the solution like this....

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/textIcons"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/lightPrimaryColor" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_contentframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/admob"
            layout="@layout/admob" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawerlist" />
```